# Angular2 Webpack lazyload TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: angular, webpack-2

I am having issues with angular-router-loader,
Where I want to lazyload a module, and I follow every guideline I saw,
and I keep getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`:

[image: The error]

Here is my `webpack.config.common.js`

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'app': './app/main.ts'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: [
                    'awesome-typescript-loader',
                    'angular2-template-loader',
                    'angular-router-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'raw-loader'
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'index.html'
        }),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and windows
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
            './app' // location of the src
        )
    ]
};
```

And here is `app.routing.ts`

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
    }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Here is the `dashboard/dashboard.module`:

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }   from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';

import { DashboardComponent }    from './dashboard.component';

import { dashboardRouting } from './dashboard.routing';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        dashboardRouting
    ],
    declarations: [
        DashboardComponent
    ],
    providers: [
    ]
})
export class DashboardModule {}
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.35",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.53",
    "angular-router-loader": "^0.5.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.18",
    "del-cli": "^0.2.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.26.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0-rc.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.2.0-rc.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^2.4.0"
  }
```

What have I been doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

try importing

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { <children routes of dashboard> } from '<path of dashboard child routes>';
```

in your **dashboard/dashboard.module** and then put this on your NgModule imports area of your **DashboardModule**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        dashboardRouting
    ],
    declarations: [
        DashboardComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(<children routes of dashboard>)
    ]
})
export class DashboardModule {}
```

Please replace the **<>** part with necessary details.